# Is it possible to import development versions of a package within another package?

Tags: r, data.table, r-devel

I am writing a package (currently for my own use only) that uses `data.table` heavily. However, one function I use often, `data.table::fcase()` is only available in the development version of `data.table`. Is it possible to ensure that `R` checks for and installs the development version of `data.table` with my package?

Comment: Not an answer to your general question, but just to let you know that `fcase` is available in [`1.13.0`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1130--24-jul-2020) which is on CRAN.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `remotes` field. Not sure if that works for CRAN. You can also just list the version under imports/depends(not recommended since these dev versions change often).